# Solution of a PDE that is almost heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the function $u(x,t)$ that satisfies the following PDE:
$$u_t = x(a_t-b\log x) u_x + \frac{1}{2}c^2 x^2 u_{xx} -xu ,\quad u(0,x)=1,$$
where $a_t$ is a known function of $t$, $b$ and $c$ are constants, $c>0$. If $b=0$ then this is the Black-Scholes equation (and it can be reduced to the heat equation).

How can I reduce this PDE to a known PDE, if possible? Does anyone know the shape of the solution? For example, in the case $b=0$ one can guess that $u(x,t)=e^{F(t)x+G(t)}$ and try to find $F$ and $G$. Can I use a similar trick here? Thanks!

PS: If relevant, I obtained this equation from applaying conditional expectation to a diffusion with drift $x(a_t-b\log x)$ and volatility term $\sigma x$ (Feynman-Kac formula). If relevant, the function $a$ is of the form $a_t=\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 t$.

Comment: This PDE is a first order linear evolution equation. There are a multitude of known techniques for these equations. See [here](https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Monographs/01/chpt4.pdf) for instance.

Comment: Is the parameter $b$ "small"? If so perhaps some perturbative type methods could be effective here.